# Web Proxy bypasses coldfusion login form to site

Tags: forms, authentication, coldfusion, proxy

I have a coldfusion login form (by using a coldfusion form, where I have a simple cfif or cfelse statement).  I noticed today that you can bypass this form entirely by using a proxy.

Can anyone point me in the direction (keywords, methods, tutorials) of ensuring proxies can't view the site, without having to login as well?

This is the process

```
<cfset this_password = "password">
<cfif form.password neq "password" or form.username neq "login">
<cflocation url="doorway_page_For_the_Key.cfm?status=le">
<cfelse>
<cflock scope="session" timeout="10">
    <cfset session.valid_user = "yes">
</cflock>
<cflocation url="home.cfm" addtoken="no">
</cfif>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have similar logic in your Application.cfc's `onCFCRequest()`, and return http error 403 with `<cfheader>` if the request is not authorized.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/onCFCRequest

You may use your own session-based authentication or http basic authentication under https.